# Best way to save email, including images and HTML data, using Java Mail API?

Tags: java, email, pdf, jakarta-mail, html-email

I'm looking for the best way to save an email body which includes inline images and HTML content. I want to Retain everything the mail contains.

> My ultimate Goal is to save the complete email body into a PDF

If there is a direct way to write email body into PDF ?

if not what would be the best format to save the email ?

I can convert HTML, DOC etc to PDF using some other available API.

```
private void downloadAttachment(Part part, String folderPath) throws Exception {
    String disPosition = part.getDisposition();
    String fileName = part.getFileName();
    String decodedText = null;
    logger.info("Disposition type :: " + disPosition);
    logger.info("Attached File Name :: " + fileName);

    if (disPosition != null && disPosition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is ATTACHMENT type.");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + decodedText);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    } else if (fileName != null && disPosition == null) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is Null type but file name is valid.  Possibly inline attchment");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + decodedText);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    } else if (fileName == null && disPosition == null) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is Null type but file name is null. It is email body.");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + "mail.html");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    }


}
     protected int saveEmailAttachment(File saveFile, Part part) throws Exception {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    int ret = 0, count = 0;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveFile));
        part.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(saveFile));

    } finally {
        try {
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            logger.error("Error while closing the stream.", ioe);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Please suggest. Thank you!

Comment: How did you create pdf , using iText or PDFBox ?. Actually I am in the same situation.Would be much help full if you could help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save it in its natural state, as a MimeMessage.

JavaMail MimeMessages can be streamed to text, since that's how they arrive in mail. For example, [MimeMessage.writeTo](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) saves the message out as text. Similarly, [MimeMessage.parse](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-) reads it back in. One in a MimeMessage, you can get the text, the attachments, etc. quite easily.

You could also stream it out as a serialized Java object, but, frankly, I wouldn't. The text representation is much more useful.

Comment: Actually i can't keep it as text. I have my messages as MimeMessage. but saving it as text will make me loose the images. I need to keep them. What other option can you suggest for this ?

Comment: If you do as Will said, you won't loose anything. In contrast to what he said, though, MimeMessages are not necessarily a pure text format, in case of a binary transfer encoding they can contain binary data sections, too.

Comment: My ultimate Goal is to save the complete email body into a PDF. Should i do it this way MimeMessage.writeTo(new OutputStream("output.pdf")) ?

Comment: PDF generated in this case gives an error stating that file is not of valid type. I don't want to save it and read it back. Just want to convert it to PDF. Should choosing a proper OutputStream work for me ?

Comment: My comment was in reply to your comment to Will's answer, not in reply to your original question. (BTW, the title of your question is misleading as you don't want to save the e-mail but instead render it as PDF; Will's answer presents a good choice for saving but not for rendering.) You appear to say that you have some other API for rendering; obviously the best format to save your data is a format which that other API understands.