# Saving emails for later view

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, email, html-email

I need to save emails I receive so that the user can view them later on. They need to be saved in such a way that the images will remain even if their links a re broken (e.g. for the images that are link and not attachments, upload them to S3 and change the links to point to them).

Can anyone recommend a library that will help me achieve that?

I was thinking of two approaches:
1) Save the email to PDF - but I have no idea how to make it correctly include the images.
2) Save the original email and render it on the client, but then it doe snot show the attached images.

Any one of those will do with preference to the first option. If its the first option then I can write it on my RoR server or as an external Python service. If its the sercond I have to write it to work on RoR.

I am aware that this question is similar to: [Best way to save email, including images and HTML data, using Java Mail API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577389/best-way-to-save-email-including-images-and-html-data-using-java-mail-api)

but I need to do it on Rails not Java.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have an auto-forwarder to a separate account? That way they would effectively be bcc'd on everything you get. I know Gmail can easily do that with filters.

Another option is forwarding the emails to a 'read it later' service and let their api do the heavy lifting. Not sure if they keep the attachment, but it is worth a look.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to save the emails so I can later display them to an end user. I do not see how saving them in a separate Gmail account would help.

Comment: Why not? It is a place to save them and display them! Gmail is a free tool with some powerful filter based forwarding. You could simply use it (or any other client) as a tool to filter and push the emails you want to share automatically to whatever place you want to store them for the end user. By keeping the messages in an email format when you send it on, that is the easiest way to keep the images and attachments in tact. Maybe you should look for a stripped down email client instead as your final viewing location...